# How to start weblogic service with another user?

Tags: services, weblogic

First I need to start weblogic service with test user but I need the process owner to be weblogic not the test user.

Second thing is I have to start weblogic with `nohup` and put it in backbground
like this `#nohup ./startweblogic &`

Things I've done are as follow:

I've added test user to sudoers so it can run the start script

I run the following command but still the process owner is not weblogic.

`#su -p -s /bin/sh weblogic  "nohup /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh &"`

Comment: Are you running a system that supports systemd? If so, are you able/willing to use that? Systemd allows (not forces) to start at system boot, run as a different user and allows other users to manage the service.

Comment: I'm running weblogic on a centos 6.8

Comment: It is working? You just want to put weblogic at start? Is only that?

Comment: As what user is the process running in your current situation when you start using sudo? What happens if you execute: sudo -b -u weblogic nohup /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh

Answer (score 2):

*edit*: "I was mistaken by thinking CentOS 6.8 already supported systemd, however, Centos only support it from 7.0"

Running Weblogic on Centos 6.8 I recommend using systemd. If you use Nodemanager you can also best use systemd for that as well and make the weblogic dependent on it.

An example systemd system file looks like this, Change paths to suit your situation, except the location of the service file.

vi /etc/systemd/system/wls_adminserver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=WebLogic Adminserver service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/data/domains/base_domain
ExecStart=/data/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh
ExecStop=/data/domains/base_domain/bin/stopWebLogic.sh
User=weblogic
Group=oinstall

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Use sudo to allow the user 'test' to execute the commands:

```
systemctl start wls_adminmanager
systemctl stop wls_adminmanager
systemctl status wls_adminmanager
```

Comment: centos 6.8 does not have systemctl command